# How to update process variables during run time in Camunda 8?

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

How to update process variables during run time in Camunda 8 in the Java logic? Below is a way to do it in camunda 7 , I am looking for camunda 8 equivalent for the same.

```
    List processInstances =
            runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery()
            .processDefinitionKey(processKey)
            .active()
            .list();
    processInstances.forEach(processInstance -> {
        List executions = runtimeService.createExecutionQuery()
                .processInstanceId(processInstance.getId())
                .list();
        executions.forEach(execution -> {
            runtimeService.setVariable(execution.getId(), variableName, variableValue);
        });
    });
```

Could not find a way to update process instance variables during run time.

Comment: Are you in the client or Server?

Comment: This is on the server side java application, to be specific in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SetVariablesRequest on the engine / zeebe API
https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-tools/grpc/#setvariables-rpc

Since you probably don't want to use gRPC, you can use the client library of choice. For Java you can use
https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-tools/java-client/, which is documented here:
https://javadoc.io/doc/io.camunda/zeebe-client-java
or the Spring Boot Wrapper for it here:
https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/spring-zeebe/

Try something along those lines:

```
@Autowired
private ZeebeClient client;

public void updateVar(Long elementInstanceKey)
{
   client.newSetVariablesCommand(elementInstanceKey).variables(Map.of("a","aval","b","bval")).send().join();
}
```

Comment: Hi rob2universe, Thanks for responding. So is there way to update variables without an activated task in a process instance? If there is process already instantiated , how do I update variables/ add more variables?

Comment: yes, you don't need to activate a task to update the data. Please try my answer and accept it if it works for you.

Comment: I have a gateway with an Incident. I can't update the variable of that instance... there is no "elementInstanceKey" that is valid for me to "set the variable" on. How to find the correct "elementInstanceKey"?

Comment: Have you tried to use the processInstanceKey?